# Hover over tags on careers.stackoverflow.com to reveal details

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs

On Stack Overflow, et al, "tags" can be hovered over to display information about
them (which then leads to their wiki). They should behave the same way on
Careers.

Comment: This. As a job seeker on Careers I sometimes see the name of an API or toolkit I'm unfamiliar with. Being able to see the flyout wiki excerpt (as pulled from SO) would be a huge improvement to the UX. I'm sure employers would find this handy when viewing candidates' profiles, too.